# How to be more Laravel in a CRUD app?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

This is a question about how to create a better application with awesome Laravel. I want to create a CRUD application with multiple forms with user's permissions.

**Details**:

1. **View**. I have 3 forms, for example lets call it `cat`, `turtle` and `dog`. The most important is that they have different number of fields. 
   [Here are forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ6MD.png)
2. **Controller**. After user filled in the form and pressed `save` button the controller in the game. All of us know that the thinner controller is the better it is. But I use construction like this:

   ```
   switch($type)
   {
       case '1':
           //form validation -> move to model
           //if all have passed that insert into database
           //Show user a message
           break;

       case '2':
           //form validation -> move to model
           //if all have passed that insert into database
           //Show user a message
           break;
   //.....

       default:
           //show message
           break;

   }
   ```

   Where variable `type` equals form's type which has been filled in by a user. But as you can see now the controller is pretty big, and I don't like it. What the best way to do this?
3. **Model**.
   I have 4 table, `dogs_data`, `turtle_data`, `cat_data` where I store all data from forms and `pets_data` where I store different metadata about pets above. How does it work? After validation passed insert data into one of these tables and get ID of this insertion. Then create the record in `pets_data` and insert the ID as `pet_id` and also insert `table_type` which will be required to get information from database. I think that it is very weird way to work with database. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvrs2.png) is table's visualisation.

Another problem is - show data. For example user has no permissions to edit data or delete records, but admin can remove, updated and see a lot of data from database. Should I create another controller like AdminController and write there another method which display information only for admin?

My application now:

1. `WebSiteController` - display website
2. `AdminController` - admin page, there is a method which generate special page to view pets.
3. `UserController` - users control panel, there is also method which generate page to view pets, but special for user.

And I think to create something like this

1. `AuthController` - special for login\registration\activation\etc
2. `PetsController` - create\delete\update\etc and also view in two variation: for `user` and `admin`. And idea is to create a method `getShowPets($pet_id)` (important it is only **id** from `pets_data`, not the **pets_id**) then get permission of the user and generate page.
3. And so on, I want to re-write my application use DRY rule

   So I will very happy if you can give me some good tips about this project.

Comment: First off it looks like your 'interesting' table situation looks like it could be a good candidate for a polymorphic relationship. You may have to change the way it works a little but the idea is there (storing the model name and id is how polymorphic relationships work). That may help you out with some currently-weird model code. As for the controller becoming fat, that's not necessarily the worst thing to do, so don't worry too much. However, have a think about moving the validation (or even form processing) into its own class (one for each type). That'll thin the controller down.

Comment: And yes, I'd suggest using a separate controller for admins - you'll be able to control permissions much more cleanly (for example using before filters that you set up in the controller) than dropping loads of `if`s inside controller methods. I guess don't worry about the seeming duplication of CRUD-like code between normal users and admins for now - you're striving for thinner controllers, and you'll find that the more you thin them out, the more you can reuse code between the two controllers using an intermediate class that doesn't have to care about that kinda stuff.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are setting up a polymorphic relation, in which case, I would make everything separate meaning you'd have a model for Cat, Dog, Turtle, and PetData.  You'd have controllers for CatController, DogController, and TurtleController.  And you'd have a Cat form, a Dog form and a Turtle form, each that also contain inputs for the data you require for your pet_info table.

To create the polymorphic relation, your pet_data table will require some changes.  Just change the table column to `pet_type`.  Laravel expects a certain name for this column and for its contents to be the name of a model rather than the name of your table.

Setting up the models for these is very easy, I'll do the PetData and the Dog one to get started.

```
class Dog extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $table = 'dogs_data';
    protected $timestamps = false;

    public function petData()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('PetData', 'pet');
    }
}

class PetData extends Eloquent
{
    protected $timestamps = false;

    public function pet()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Can read more about this here... http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations

The idea of having separate models/controllers for everything might seem like a lot of work, but it goes a long way when trying to maintain or add additional animals to your app because you should rarely have to modify production code, taking away the possibility of introducing more bugs when trying to add enhancements to your website.

Now it becomes very easy to save a pet and related pet data without having to worry about the pet_id and pet_type in the pet_data table, Laravel will take care of that for you.  The function on your dog controller might look like this...

```
class DogController extends BaseController
{
    public function save()
    {
        $dog = new Dog;
        $dog->name = Input::get('name');
        $dog->age = Input::get('age');
        $dog->save();

        $pet_data = new PetData;
        $pet_data->color = Input::get('color');
        $dog->petData()->save($pet_data);
    }
}
```

As far as creating another controller for admins, I would say yes, do that.  It never hurts to keep parts of your website that you consider different in different files.  It not only helps with organization, but again, with separation of concerns, which you should probably read more about.

There are also some fantastic 3rd party options for managing roles.  I've used `zizaco/entrust` before and found it very easy to manage.  It might make your life a lot easier when trying to manage who can do what on your web app.

Comment: _As far as creating another controller for admins, I would say yes, do that_ Do you mean to create `AdminCatController`,  `AdminDogController`, etc or just add methods into `CatController`, etc only for admin, like `function getShowAdminForm()`?