# Eloquent, morph and selecting

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

Today I'll get a lot of information about Eloquent in Laravel 4. 
So, I find out some information about morph in laravel. I've discussed it today in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182137/how-to-be-more-laravel-in-a-crud-app).

Yes, it funny, but now I want to know about fetching information. In my app I have a long query with unions, like

> $query_1 = bla->bla->bla();
>
> $query_2 = bla->bla->bla();
>
> $combine = bla->bla->bla->union($query_1)->union->($query_2);

And after modify my table has two columns(using [this idea](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations)). Also its important to have an ability to fetch data with different params. 
This of course works, but when I want to modify it's become pretty difficult and I want to know how to rewrite this by using some Laravel tips and tricks, because I've found the Eloquent very powerful system.

Comment: So what do you need help with?

Comment: Well, I want to re-write my pretty ugly query which fetch all records from 3 tables by using some features in laravel.

Comment: The last thing which I've found: create two methods. The first one select data from one table and the second one from the other table. And then save it into array.

Comment: Playing around, and I think the better idea is to leave alone this "joins-tree-query". But maybe I should modify it? Now I have pet_type which stores table name. Is there some function which can use data from pet_type field?

Comment: Why don't you use that polymorphic relation? It's exactly what you need here.